# Display modal card on first page load

Tags: typescript, angular6

I'm new to Angular, I have modal card that will open if users had succesful login,but it will open  everytime the page is refresh and what I need its to open on first page load only,below is my code,

```
userAuthenticated(): void {
    this.authenticationService.getCurrentUser().subscribe(obj => {
        if (obj.currentKycLevel === null) this.kycLevel = 0
        if (this.kycLevel === 0) {
            const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MatDialogComponent, {
                width: '500px',
                data: {
                    header: 'Upgrade your Limits',
                    body: {},
                    modalType: 'user-setting'
                }
            });
            dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
            });
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save a flag in your localstorage variable, that will remains even when you refresh the page.
Just set it false when you login

Save into LocalStorage variable

```
localStorage.setItem('key', value);
```

Get from LocalStorage variable

```
localStorage.getItem('key');
```